# Can php-fpm service interpret environment variables inside www.conf to create unique log files?

Tags: php, environment-variables, configuration-files

I'm trying to set multiple cloud servers behind an ALB to write their log files to my common EFS. I have a single shared drive EFS, which I can access via a single development instance, while all my production instances are securely behind a VCN. I am trying to use system environment variables (specifically the HOSTNAME) so that each of the production instances, which use the same configuration file to start php-fpm (so that I can do auto-scaling), write a different log.

I've seen answers that say that the *nix way of using environment variables should work, but they are not working for me. Specifically ${HOSTNAME} returns blank (and I have checked it *is* set for the apache and root users; root starts the php-frm service). I also tried interpolations of that, and the bash flavor of things "%()". None of them work.

All of them return blank strings (but not errors).

I did create a single variable in my environment variable, and got that to work.

I also read that you can't assign a env value to a variable directly, but when I tried to create a separate variable, that actually returned an error when starting the service.

This is what I would expect to work:

```
slowlog = "/shared/logs/php-fpm/www-slow-${HOSTNAME}.log"
```

Tried all of the following:

```
slowlog = "/shared/logs/php-fpm/www-slow-".${HOSTNAME}.".log"
```

--> blank for hostname

```
slowlog = "/shared/logs/php-fpm/www-slow-${HOSTNAME}.log"
```

--> blank for hostname

```
slowlog = "/shared/logs/php-fpm/www-slow-%(HOSTNAME).log"
```

--> the file name includes %(HOSTNAME)

```
slowlog = "/shared/logs/php-fpm/www-slow-$HOSTNAME.log"
```

--> the file name includes $HOSTNAME

```
slowlog = "/shared/logs/php-fpm/www-slow-{$HOSTNAME}.log"
```

--> the file name includes {$HOSTNAME}

```
slowlog_name = "/shared/logs/php-fpm/www-slow-{$HOSTNAME}.log"
slowlog = slowlog_name
```

--> start error: unknown variable slowlog_name

Thank you for any tips/advice!

Comment: Have you looked at the manual? Does it give any indication that you can do this?

Answer (score 1):

PHP 7.3 does support environment variable interpolation for log file names in config files - I just tested this.  I suspect that where you're getting caught is that in bash, `$HOSTNAME` is a bash variable but not automatically an environment variable, and Linux systems vary in whether `$HOSTNAME` is set as an environment variable.  RedHat distros do set it, Ubuntu does not:

```
jacob@nitrogen ~ $ cat /etc/redhat-release 
Fedora release 29 (Twenty Nine)
jacob@nitrogen ~ $ echo $HOSTNAME
nitrogen
jacob@nitrogen ~ $ env | grep HOSTNAME
HOSTNAME=nitrogen

jacob@iad11:~$ grep PRETTY_NAME /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"
jacob@iad11:~$ echo $HOSTNAME
iad11
jacob@iad11:~$ env | grep HOSTNAME
```

You can test with a different environment variable, and then set `$HOSTNAME` in a custom startup script that then starts PHP.